# numbering of features when dissolving non-contiguous polygons

Tags: multipart, unique-id

I have dissolved polygons together to make feature A. Some of the polygons are contiguous and some are not. Therefore, there is a unique row for each feature (singlepart to multipart).

In ArcGIS or SAS how are the features assigned a unique ID?

Is the largest feature given the first ID?

Comment: I don't think it's safe to make **any** assumption of order in assignment.